# Improve performance of a recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion, biginteger

I would like to calculate big numbers of a sequence, which is described by the following recursion:

```
x(0,w)=1
x(1,w)=w
x(n+1,w)= 2*w*x(n,w)-x(n-1)
```

My project is already implemented in Java, that is I need a Java solution to this issue.

The aim is to calculate x(k,w), where w has been calculated before and k, w are BigIntegers. As k and w are such great numbers, the calculation needs a lot of time.

I have already implemented a solution using an ArrayList of BigIntegers, which worked out well for small numbers only. Then, as I only need x(k,w) and not all the numbers of the sequence, I could come up with the following solution, which still was a lot to slow:

```
BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");

BigInteger x_2 = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger x_1 = w;

BigInteger x_0 = BigInteger.ZERO;

for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(k) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        x_0 = w.multiply(TWO).multiply(x_1).subtract(x_2);

        x_2 = x_1;
        x_1 = x_0;

    }

return x_0;
```

Do you know any way to improve the speed of that algorithm?

One idea was to calculate an explicit function for the sequence, which should be

```
x(n,w)=1/2*((w+sqrt(w^2-1)^n+(w-sqrt(w^2-1)^n)
```

But Java does not offer implemented methods to calculate powers or squareroots of BigInteger/BigDecimal-objects. One can acutally avoid to calculate the squareroots, as they cancel out later. But then, one has to calculate binomial coefficients. Therefore, I am not sure about which methods I should implement.

Can you tell me, which you think is the fastest and most efficient way to (exactly) calculate x(k,w)?

Comment: Try pre-calculating low values of x(n, w) and storing them in a `Map`.  If you restrict the pre-calculation to `int` or `long` values then it will run faster; just convert to `BigInteger` before storing the result in the `Map`.  You also need to implement different approaches and run timings to check for speed.

Comment: Your title asks about a recursion, but the code you've presented appears to be iterative.

Comment: I am not quite sure, if a pre-calculation with long values will work out. k is in some cases a number greater than 530 000 000. That is, precalculating with integers would only reduce a tiny fraction of the whole computing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n`-th term is a linear combination of the previous two and the coefficient are the same for all `n`, so you can find the `n`-th power of the matrix `[[2 * w, -1], [1, 0]]` and multiply it by the vector `[x_1, x_0]`. If you use binary matrix exponentiation, you'll need `O(log n)` multiplications and additions. This solution uses only integer numbers, so it's absolutely precise.